CSS go backwords from input:checked using nth
I am building a multi item css only carousel that uses input radios and the navigation as the labels.


body {
  padding: 200px;
}

.wrapper {
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  background: #eee;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 600px;
  position: relative;
}

input {
  display: none !important;
}

input:checked+.item {
  margin-left: unset;
}

input:checked+.item span {
  outline: 2px solid #0000ff;
  color: #0000ff;
}

input:checked+.item+label {
  color: #0000ff;
}

input:checked+.item~.item {
  margin-left: unset;
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: none;
  left: 50%;
}

input:checked+.item+label+input+.item+label {
  margin-left: 100px;
}

input:checked+.item+label,
input:checked+.item+label+input+.item+label {
  display: block;
}

input:checked+.item:nth-of-type(-n + 4)+label:nth-of-type(-n + 4) {
  display: block;
}

.item {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  margin-left: -25%;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.item span {
  margin: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.item:nth-last-child(-n + 12) {
  _margin-left: unset;
}
<div class="wrapper">

  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide_1">
  <div class="item"><span>Allison</span></div>
  <label class="nav" for="slide_1"> 1 </label><input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide_2">
  <div class="item"><span>Arthur</span></div>
  <label class="nav" for="slide_2"> 2 </label><input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide_3" checked="">
  <div class="item"><span>Ana</span></div>
  <label class="nav" for="slide_3"> 3 </label><input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide_4">
  <div class="item"><span>Alex</span></div>
  <label class="nav" for="slide_4"> 4 </label><input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide_5">
  <div class="item"><span>Arlene</span></div>
  <label class="nav" for="slide_5"> 5 </label><input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide_6">
  <div class="item"><span>Alberto</span></div>
  <label class="nav" for="slide_6"> 6 </label><input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide_7">
  <div class="item"><span>Barry</span></div>
  <label class="nav" for="slide_7"> 7 </label><input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide_8">
  <div class="item"><span>Bertha</span></div>
  <label class="nav" for="slide_8"> 8 </label><input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide_9">
  <div class="item"><span>Bill</span></div>
  <label class="nav" for="slide_9"> 9 </label>

</div>



If you click the unhighlighted numbers the carousel will go right.
The current checked carousel is highlighted in blue color and cannot go left since is checked, and needs a nth selector to go backwords from the input:checked to the label and show it.
If the current input checked is "3", the labels needs to show "2", "3", "4".
I've been trying to do:
input:checked + .item:nth-of-type(-n + 4) + label:nth-of-type(-n + 4) {
    display: block;
}

But the code selects only the label followed by input:checked
Hope it make sense.

+ is called the next sibling combinator, because you can only use it to select siblings following your initial element, you can not use to it select any previous siblings. Using :has() on the parent it might be possible to implement what you want ... only, I would advise against it to begin with: "CSS only" solutions to stuff like this usually come with serious usability drawbacks. Using JavaScript, and setting / toggling of appropriate aria attributes, does a much better job in that regard.

This can be achieved with the :has() pseudo-class (as @CBroe already suggested and explained the drawbacks).
It's capable of selecting elements using an additional condition: select a label that is followed by input that is :checked.
label:has( + input:checked) {
 display: block;
 margin-left: -100px;
}

Snippet:


body {
  padding: 200px;
}

.wrapper {
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  background: #eee;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 600px;
  position: relative;
}

input {
  display: none !important;
}

input:checked+.item {
  margin-left: unset;
}

input:checked+.item span {
  outline: 2px solid #0000ff;
  color: #0000ff;
}

input:checked+.item+label {
  color: #0000ff;
}

input:checked+.item~.item {
  margin-left: unset;
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: none;
  left: 50%;
}

label:has( + input:checked) {
  display: block;
  margin-left: -100px;
}

input:checked+.item+label+input+.item+label {
  margin-left: 100px;
}

input:checked+.item+label,
input:checked+.item+label+input+.item+label {
  display: block;
}

input:checked+.item:nth-of-type(-n + 4)+label:nth-of-type(-n + 4) {
  display: block;
}

.item {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  margin-left: -25%;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.item span {
  margin: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.item:nth-last-child(-n + 12) {
  _margin-left: unset;
}
<div class="wrapper">

  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide_1">
  <div class="item"><span>Allison</span></div>
  <label class="nav" for="slide_1"> 1 </label><input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide_2">
  <div class="item"><span>Arthur</span></div>
  <label class="nav" for="slide_2"> 2 </label><input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide_3" checked="">
  <div class="item"><span>Ana</span></div>
  <label class="nav" for="slide_3"> 3 </label><input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide_4">
  <div class="item"><span>Alex</span></div>
  <label class="nav" for="slide_4"> 4 </label><input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide_5">
  <div class="item"><span>Arlene</span></div>
  <label class="nav" for="slide_5"> 5 </label><input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide_6">
  <div class="item"><span>Alberto</span></div>
  <label class="nav" for="slide_6"> 6 </label><input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide_7">
  <div class="item"><span>Barry</span></div>
  <label class="nav" for="slide_7"> 7 </label><input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide_8">
  <div class="item"><span>Bertha</span></div>
  <label class="nav" for="slide_8"> 8 </label><input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide_9">
  <div class="item"><span>Bill</span></div>
  <label class="nav" for="slide_9"> 9 </label>

</div>



